# How to get only updated column values from two tables having same table structure

Tags: sql, join

There are two tables with same structure,in the first table, there is main data and in another table, there is data that is recently updated. for. eg

table A --

```
col1 col2 col3
abc  xyz  yyz
```

table B--

```
col1 col2 col3
abc  pqr  yyz
```

as i update the value for col2 in tableB now i want the query which will give in old value from table A and new value from table B. i.e.

```
oldValue  NewValuwe
xyz       pqr
```

Comment: Do the tables have only one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the sample data that you've posted, I'm assuming col1 in both the tables would not be updated, and hence can be used to link the two tables

```
Select
   a.col1,
   CASE
      WHEN NVL(a.col2, '') <> NVL(b.col2, '') THEN a.col2 
      WHEN NVL(a.col3, '') <> NVL(b.col3, '') THEN a.col3 
      -- and so on
      ELSE 'None' 
   END
   AS oldValue, 
   CASE
      WHEN NVL(a.col2, '') <> NVL(b.col2, '') THEN b.col2 
      WHEN NVL(a.col3, '') <> NVL(b.col3, '') THEN b.col3 
      -- and so on
      ELSE 'None' 
   END
   AS NewValue 
from
   tableA a, tableB b 
where
   a.col1 = b.col1 
   and 
   (
      NVL(a.col2, '') <> NVL(b.col2, '') 
      OR NVL(a.col3, '') <> NVL(b.col3, '') -- assuming you want to track changes of col3 as well
   )
```

Comment: If it helped you, could you please accept this as answer.

Comment: yes, it gives me exactly what i want.how to accept it?

Comment: Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.

Comment: case i can use till 10 interval what to do if i have to chek this for all columns?